# Cypher - variable length matching not showing all relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a tree with an unknown number of nodes and relationships, Starting from a single node, I need to return **all** nodes and relationships connected to that node (up to 5 hops). The problem I encountered is that when using a variable path larger than 2, the query does not return some of the nodes connected to the starting point.

This query returns 137 nodes:

```
MATCH (n)-[*1..5]->(q) WHERE n.name='Bob' RETURN * LIMIT 500
```

And this query returns 300 nodes :

```
MATCH (n)-[*1..2]->(q) WHERE n.name='Bob' RETURN * LIMIT 500
```

How is this possible? doesn't variable length return all nodes from Y to X hops?

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental in how variable length works, but couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it should. Do you have an example of your data set? What happens if you use `RETURN DISTINCT q`?

Comment: It works! I got all the data. But isn't DISTINCT suppose to prevent duplicates? Why does [*1..2] show the first hop nodes and [1..5] doesn't?

Comment: I have no idea. My guess would be some difference in the query that's being overlooked, like a missing directional arrow on the relationship that's *1..2, but if you're running what you pasted, then I can't see a problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can return all nodes and relationships using DISTINCT? I tried `MATCH (n)-[*1..5]->(q) WHERE n.name='Bob' RETURN DISTINCT * LIMIT 1000` and I still get partial results - 306 nodes but when using `DISTINCT q` I get 743 results.

Comment: Do you still get weird numbers when you just `RETURN q`? Also, what version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: You may also want to PROFILE both queries and try to figure out where they differ

Comment: Right. Well, that number makes sense, there would be more nodes without using DISTINCT. For now I'd just avoid using `RETURN *` and be explicit about what you're returning. I'll see if I can find out anything on why `RETURN *` might do this.

Comment: It seems that when using `DISTINCT q` I get **all** the nodes and relationships, ignoring the predicate. This can explain why I get more nodes than before. So, for now, I'm using `RETURN n,r,q`. Thanks for your help @InverseFalcon!